# Push android's project to GIT repo

Tags: android, git

I clone some libraries to my android's project, evertying works fine, when I finish my works I try to push it to my repo but it gives me that problem :

> Counting objects: 1937, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (1839/1839), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (1937/1937), 27.24 MiB | 5.83 MiB/s, done. Total 1937 (delta 703),
>   reused 0 (delta 0) error: RPC failed; result=22, **HTTP code = 413**
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote end hung
>   up unexpectedly Everything up-to-date

this my .gitignore :

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/forecast-master
/headerlistview
/library-sliding-menu
/progresswheel-master
/stripe-android-master
/uil_library
/facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0
/android-rss-reader-library-master
```

when I delet those projects the push works correctly, so why to .gitIgnore dosen't work ? and why the push gives me the error above ?

Comment: When do you delete what projects ?

Comment: the libraries wich I cloned, it contains .git floder so maybe this folder is the root of the problem, may I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is :  I found a .git file in a sub-directory, when I deleted the push works fine.